# alternate way to read excel files without providing "network service" security

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am using a web application to read the excel file and uploading it in the database.

I have deployed the application in the server.I am using windows service 2003 as the server.I am able to read the excel file only if i set the set the security settings to  "network service"  for the microsoft excel application in the control panel --> administrative tools --> componetn service -- > computer -- > My computer -- >DCOM config -- > microsoft excel application .

Why is it so . There are also other applications running in the server.

1) Doing like this will create any issue ?

2) Why do we need to do it ?

3) Is there any alternative way to do it ?

4) What are we doing actually by providing network service access ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2) I can only speculate that this is required because your ASP.NET application is a service.

3) You could use [SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) which is a safe managed assembly which does not require FullTrust (although you will of course need access to any workbooks you are trying to load).

You can see ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC